# AWK usage issue while archiving HDFS files in Hortonworks Distribution

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to move files in a HDFS directory that are over 3 days old to an archiving folder in HDFS.

AWK Script:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current | tail -n+2 | xargs -n 8 |
awk '{
DAY_CONV=(60*60*24);
X ="date +%s";X | getline ED;printf("") > "X";close("X");
Y="date -d \"$6\" +%s";Y | getline SD;printf("") > "Y";close("Y");
DIFF=(ED-SD)/DAY_CONV;
print " SD=",SD" ED=",ED," DIFF=",DIFF," INPUT=",$6;
if ( DIFF -gt 3)
cmd="hdfs dfs -ls " $8;
system(cmd);
}'
```

Note: cmd variable would have a mv command once this script starts working

Issue:

- Value of variable X is constant
- Value of Variable Y is constant
- Unable to get day difference between 2 date , i get fraction value in DIFF
- If statement in AWK is failing due to inaccurate arguments

Input to AWK:

```
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 50687424 2017-02-27 17:06 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.240220170000
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 49967359 2017-02-27 17:06 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.250220170000
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 28647041 2017-02-27 17:00 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.260220170000
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6728724 2017-03-01 13:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1305
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 7050854 2017-03-01 13:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1325
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6630106 2017-03-01 13:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1345
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6766650 2017-03-01 14:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1405
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6486095 2017-03-01 14:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1425
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6350705 2017-03-01 14:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1445
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6082589 2017-03-01 15:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1505
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6417281 2017-03-01 15:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1525
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6519949 2017-03-01 15:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1545
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6988534 2017-03-01 16:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1605
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6734459 2017-03-01 16:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1625
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6842766 2017-03-01 16:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1645
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6575513 2017-03-01 17:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1705
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 6574050 2017-03-01 17:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1725
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 50215096 2017-02-27 18:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-27_1801
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 50985760 2017-02-27 18:18 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-27_1818
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 58206776 2017-02-28 00:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_0001
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 58823497 2017-02-28 06:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_0601
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 61591660 2017-02-28 12:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_1201
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 59703667 2017-03-01 10:40 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_1801
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 59160075 2017-03-01 10:47 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_0001
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 61812121 2017-03-01 10:48 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_0601
-rw-r--r-- 3 user hdfs 63804772 2017-03-01 12:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_1201
```

Output from AWK (Has debugging prints):

```
  SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-27
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   50687424 2017-02-27 17:06 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.240220170000
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-27
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   49967359 2017-02-27 17:06 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.250220170000
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-27
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   28647041 2017-02-27 17:00 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/Conversation.json.260220170000
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6728724 2017-03-01 13:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1305
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    7050854 2017-03-01 13:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1325
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6630106 2017-03-01 13:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1345
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6766650 2017-03-01 14:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1405
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6486095 2017-03-01 14:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1425
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6350705 2017-03-01 14:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1445
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6082589 2017-03-01 15:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1505
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6417281 2017-03-01 15:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1525
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6519949 2017-03-01 15:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1545
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6988534 2017-03-01 16:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1605
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6734459 2017-03-01 16:25 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1625
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6842766 2017-03-01 16:45 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1645
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs    6575513 2017-03-01 17:05 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation.json.2017-03-01_1705
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-27
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   50215096 2017-02-27 18:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-27_1801
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-27
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   50985760 2017-02-27 18:18 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-27_1818
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-28
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   58206776 2017-02-28 00:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_0001
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-28
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   58823497 2017-02-28 06:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_0601
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-02-28
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   61591660 2017-02-28 12:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_1201
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   59703667 2017-03-01 10:40 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-02-28_1801
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   59160075 2017-03-01 10:47 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_0001
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   61812121 2017-03-01 10:48 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_0601
 SD= 1488286800 ED= 1488348518  DIFF= 0.714329  INPUT= 2017-03-01
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs   63804772 2017-03-01 12:01 hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current/conversation_6hr.json.2017-03-01_1201
```

Distribution Information:

- Hortonworks
- Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169
- Linux dh01 aaaaaaaaaaaaa.x86_64 #1 SMP   Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any input will be greatly helpfull.

Comment: `-gt` is a bash operator. With `awk` you should use `>`

Comment: @Kfactor21 - Can you please paste your expected output.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR .. for the input that i have posted there should not be any output. All files in my input are less than 3 days old.
Hence the ` hdfs dfs -ls ` command inside of "IF" statement should not execute. But right now it is because DIFF variable does not have the correct  date difference value.

Comment: @oliv .. thanks for highlighting the correct operator .. but also i think there is also an issue with ED (End date) calculation. for all the input Records ED is constant where as in the input to awk there are 3 different End Dates (2017-02-27,2017-02-28,2017-03-01).

Comment: @Kfactor21 You're right. Your `getline` statement is pretty ugly... I advise you to use the `awk` builtin time functions: `mktime`, `sfrtime` and `systime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://companycluster/data/src/purecloud/current | tail -n+2 | xargs -n 8 \
| awk '
      BEGIN {
        # take the time reference (3 days before now)
        R = systime() - 3 * 86400
        }
      # for each line
      {
      # format used by mktime "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
      # create the time in mktime format
      t = $6 " " $7 " 00";gsub( /[-:]/, " ", t)
      # convert in epoch
      T = mktime( t )
      # if lower than reference time
      if( T < R ) {
         print "Included line: " $0

         # do what you want as action
         cmd = "hdfs dfs -ls " $8
         system( cmd )
         }
       else {
         print "Discarted line: $0"
         }
      }'
```

Comment:

- self commented awk
- the input to awk could certainly be optimized (awk do tail very well and xargs is certainly not mandatory here [no hdfs to test from here])

Comment: thanks your help. The script does the required archiving.